# Is it possible for a contract to auto-execute a function every hour?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, javascript, scheduling

I have a contract with a manual function that checks the balance of the contract and if it's zero it changes certain values in mapping. How to make this happen automatically every hour?

Answer (score 1):

No. An externally owned account has to kick it off with a signed transaction.

You can use your own server, farm it out to an Oracle or even incentivize users by paying them to initiate the process.

Hope it helps.